# Loop Attribute number increasing the value by 5 each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add an attribute to the `div` below. However I want each value to increase by `5`. For some reason when I try the code below, it repeats the number rather than increasing it by `5`.

```
<div class="yo">TOOTO</div>
<div class="yo">TOOTO</div>
<div class="yo">TOOTO</div>
<div class="yo">TOOTO</div>
```

```js
var text = "";
var i = 0.7;
while (i < 80) {
    $('.yo').attr('wow', i)
    i += 5
}
```

Comment: `$('.yo')` select all elements with `yo` class name.so you set attribute to all elements each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text = "";
var i = 0.7;
var j = 0;
while (i < 80) {

 $('.yo').eq(j).attr('wow', i)
 j++;
 i+=5
}
```

Select one element at the time,`$('.yo')` returns an array.

**EDIT**

Consider replacing `while(i < 80)` with `while($('.yo).eq(j))` if you want to set attribute in all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `$('.yo').attr('wow', i)` will update attribute value of all elements with class `yo`.

Use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method with a callback which iterates over the elements and then generates the attribute value based on the index of the element.

```
var i = 0.7;

$('.yo').attr('wow', function(i1) {
  return i + i1 * 5;
})
```

```js
var i = 0.7;

$('.yo').attr('wow', function(i1) {
  return i + i1 * 5;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="yo">
  TOOTO
</div>
<div class="yo">
  TOOTO
</div>
<div class="yo">
  TOOTO
</div>
<div class="yo">
  TOOTO
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let yo = document.getElementsByClassName("yo");
let i = 0.7;
while (i < 80) {
    yo.forEach((v, index) => v.setAttribute('wow', (index + 1) * i));
    i += 5;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.